# How to set layout_gravity center to view in LinearLayout in a DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, center, drawerlayout

I am having trouble of setting views to center in a DrawerLayout. The DrawerLayout is set to left. I wanna set the inside view to center, but they always turn out to layout to the left. how can I make it. Please help out. Many thanks. here are the layout xml.

main_layout.xml

```
 <!--<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout--> 
    <LinearLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >

 <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >
     <!-- The main content view -->
     <FrameLayout
                 android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     <fragment
             android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
         android:layout_width="240dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:name="com.onandroid.hplus.ui.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
         tools:layout="@layout/form_new" />

     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

form_add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="240dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 >

 <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/et_device_code"
     android:textColorHint="@color/text"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bar_code_white_24"
     android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_action_refresh"
     android:enabled="false"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     />
 <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/et_device_locale"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:textColorHint="@color/text"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_white_24"
     />
 <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/et_device_name"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:textColorHint="@color/text"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_abc_white_24"
     />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/bt_form_ok"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/bt_form_cancle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out, ugly though. Please see if I missed anything.
The problem here is the attributes(layout_width, layout_height, layout_gravity)  of LinearLayout in fragment NavigationDrawerFragment are of no effect, they just inhered from parent view layout of fragment.
So I have to set attributes(layout_width, layout_height, layout_gravity) of widges in LinearLayout specifically. the sublayout of fragment is as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="240dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 >

 <EditText
         android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/et_device_code"
     android:textColorHint="@color/text"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bar_code_white_24"
     android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_action_refresh"
     android:enabled="false"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     />
 <EditText
         android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/et_device_locale"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:textColorHint="@color/text"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_white_24"
     />
 <EditText
         android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/et_device_name"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:textColorHint="@color/text"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_abc_white_24"
     />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/bt_form_ok"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/bt_form_cancle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```